# Flutter: Output and Record information of checkboxes in StreamBuilder

Tags: flutter

How do I output checkboxes for every item returned in a Streambuilder and also record that information to do something with it later? I do not know how many items will be outputted and so I have no idea how many variables I should use to check the status of checkboxes. I also attached a rudimentary UI to sketch what I want the streambuilder to look like and record. *Note: I am currently in a stateless widget, however, I can change it to stateful if necessary*

Code to StreamBulder

```
StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
                                      stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance
                                          .collection("children")
                                          .where("parentUID",
                                              isEqualTo: FirebaseAuth
                                                  .instance.currentUser!.uid)
                                          .orderBy('timestamp',
                                              descending: true)
                                          .snapshots(),
                                      builder: (BuildContext context,
                                          AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot>
                                              snapshot) {
                                        if (snapshot.hasError) {
                                          return const Text(
                                              'Something went wrong');
                                        }

                                        if (snapshot.connectionState ==
                                            ConnectionState.waiting) {
                                          return const Text("Loading");
                                        }
                                        return Column(
                                          children: snapshot.data!.docs.map(
                                            (DocumentSnapshot document) {
                                              Map<String, dynamic> data =
                                                  document.data()!
                                                      as Map<String, dynamic>;

                                              return Row(
                                                crossAxisAlignment:
                                                    CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                                                children: [
                                                  /*Output a checkbox for every result returned and name its title 'data['childUserName']'. Then, I want to be able to record the responses of those checkboxes and save them when I run a function.*/
                                                ],
                                              );
                                            },
                                          ).toList(),
                                        );
                                      },
                                    ),
```

UIX
[image]

Image of Firebase
[image]

Answer (score 0):

make **List of bool** and use it at **for in loop**

here is simple example :

```
List<bool> checkboxValues = [];
int i = 0;

for (child in childern) {
  checkboxValues.add(false);
  i++;
}

CheckBox(
  value: checkboxValues[i],
  onChanged: (value) {
    checkboxValues[i] = value;
  },
)
```